# MYSQL- Grab the last 5 rows AFTER sorting them by date

Tags: mysql, datetime, sorting, alias

I'm trying to execute a MYSQL command which grabs all the rows with the given UserID, sorts them by date, then returns only the first 5.

The command to sort is

```
ORDER BY date
```

and the command to get the last 5 is

```
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
```

The WHERE comes before the ORDER, so it's backwards. So I figured I have to have a Mysql statement within a mysql statement.

Here is my attempt. I was getting an alias error, so i added the AS T1 to the command.

```
SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT voting_id, caption_uid, voting_date, rating FROM voting 
   WHERE user_id = $inUserID  AS T1 
    ORDER BY voting_date) 
 WHERE ROWNUM <= 5 AS T2;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you are working with MySQL, why not use the `LIMIT` clause, to only keep the first 5 results ?

```
select *
from your_table
order by your_column
limit 0, 5
```

Quoting a portion of [the manual page for `select`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) :

> The `LIMIT` clause can be used to constrain the number of rows
>   returned by the `SELECT` statement. `LIMIT` takes one or two numeric
>   arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants *(except
>   when using prepared statements)*. 
>  
> With two arguments, the
>   first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and
>   the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return.

Comment: Note that you can also specify just the limit if the offset is 0: `limit 5`. In fact, that's the more idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: Works like a charm, and much cleaner. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select voting_id, caption_uid, voting_date, rating from voting
where user_id = $inUserID
order by voting_date
limit 5
```

**Edit:**

It is not clear whether you want the first or last 5. If you want the last five then the order by should be:

```
order by voting_date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
Select columns from table_name where user_id =x  order by dateField desc Limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I am confuse with your title, and your question body.
You mentioned last 5 records. in the first sentence of your question, it is first 5.
A few words later, it is last 5 again.

If you want to get last 5, you may use this

```
select * from table order by date limit (select count(*)-5 from table),5
```

if you need to take care of less than 5 total records, you need to use the following:

```
select * from table order by date limit (select case when count(*)>=5 then count(*)-5 else 0 end case from table),5
```

If you can use stored procedure, the performance will be faster when you are in the 2nd example.

```
declare @total;
select @total = count(*) from `table`;
case when @total<5 then
@total=0;
else //mysql require case / else
end case;
select * from `table` order by `date` limit @total, 5
```